# Hazelcast using HD

Tags: hazelcast

I am trying to test hazelcast hd.

```
<map name="testMap">
    <!-- <in-memory-format>BINARY</in-memory-format> -->
    <in-memory-format>NATIVE</in-memory-format>
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
    <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>
    <read-backup-data>false</read-backup-data>      
</map>

<native-memory allocator-type="POOLED" enabled="true">
    <size unit="GIGABYTES" value="150"/>
</native-memory>
```

I have no idea where the data is stored. Checked with management center and found max native memory is 30G but used is always 0.

Log from node  below:
INFO: [192.168.129.155]:5701 [dev] [3.5.1] processors=4, physical.memory.total=38.4G, physical.memory.free=2.3G, swap.space.total=1024.0M, swap.space.free=997.4M, heap.memory.used=261.6M, heap.memory.free=205.4M, heap.memory.total=467.0M, heap.memory.max=8.5G, heap.memory.used/total=56.01%, heap.memory.used/max=3.00%, native.memory.used=0, native.memory.free=30.6G, native.memory.total=0, native.memory.max=30.6G, minor.gc.count=324, minor.gc.time=3225ms, major.gc.count=1, major.gc.time=74ms, load.process=100.00%, load.system=100.00%, load.systemAverage=0.40, thread.count=57, thread.peakCount=61, cluster.timeDiff=3, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operation.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.remote.size=0, operations.running.size=0, operations.pending.invocations.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, proxy.count=2, clientEndpoint.count=1, connection.active.count=13, client.connection.count=1, connection.count=9

Heap memory does not increase, non heap no change & native no change where is the data stored.

Am i missing some thing?

Update: using hazelcast version 3.5 and management center version 3.5 they are licensed version

Comment: I don't really have an idea yet but the Hazelcast version is pretty old. Can you please test with a current version (3.8.1) and see if the problem still exists?

Comment: Further, when using native memory for 5 million record size shon by management cluster is ~2GB, when i switch to binary size shoots up to ~20 GB.

Comment: As a customer with license you can always send your question to support@hazelcast.com. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use hazelcast and management center version 3.8.1.
The latest version of management center shows memory consumption and entries cost for binary and native memory.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vik Gamov, let me get a trial version to start with and then go for upgrades.